# ESP8266 and USBasp V2.0

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

Can I program the ESP8266 module via USBasp V2.0 and Arduino IDE, or do I need to get a different kind of programming stick?

Here're the pins of the USBasp:

[image]

The ESP8266 has the rolling pin setup:

[image]

My current setup: USBasp (left) --- ESP8266 (right)

- Pin2 - VCC --- (3.3V) VCC
- Pin4 - TXD --- Pin TX
- Pin6 - RXD --- Pin RX

All remaining ESP8266 pins go to ground on the USBasp.

When connecting to my Mac and starting Arduino IDE, the USBasp board and the ESP8266 LEDs light up.

Problem:

The USBasp does not show up in the Port section. Whenever I'm trying to upload a sketch these errors show up:

`error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed`

Questions:

- Can I flash an ESP8266 with a USBasp V2.0
- Is the setup correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch rx an tx pins on one side. Then you need to pull CH_PD pin on the ESP to VCC and when you upload to the ESP you need to pull GPIO0 to GND before you apply power.

- Pin2 - VCC --- (3.3V) VCC
- Pin2 - VCC --- CH_PD
- Pin4 - TXD --- Pin RX
- Pin6 - RXD --- Pin TX
- Pin8 - GND --- GPIO 0 (only when programming)

Leave ESP RESET pin floating

Then the last thing. It looks like the USBasp are 5v so you would need another power supply for the ESP witch is 3.3v.

Comment: You should use a shift level converter, bidirectional, if you dont want to break down your esp, because it only admits 0- 3.3v in its pins----

Comment: My USB ASP has a 5/3.3v jumper!